# Mobile App with Ionic and Gimbal beacon?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ibeacon-android, gimbal

I want to create mobile app that can integrated with [Gimbal](http://www.gimbal.com) beacon. This app allow us to order meal/drink while we walk through the store.

I use [ionic](http://www.ionicframework.com) as a front end. The next step is i want to integrate the app with beacon (gimbal). Should i use another framework/technology? 
Is ionic have plugin to work with gimbal? 
Is there anyone have experience before created app like that with ionic?

I've found a plugin that only support on iOS : https://github.com/happydenn/cordova-plugin-gimbal
What if i also want to create this app work on android?

Advice and explanation would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The plugin you found is not official so there is the possibility that there will be no support or updates.

Comment: ya. I think so. Do you have any advice/clue?